# Populating a prototype cell with an array that's populated using Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

How would I fill the TableView Cell using Firebase? I'm trying to fill it using an array which would be filled by Firebase, but since the data is filled asynchronously, I don't know how to make the array filled with data outside of the getData() function. As of now the data is filled inside the completion handler, but outside of that it is nil.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ProxiesListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var ProxiesTableView: UITableView!

var proxyname:[String] = []
var proxyprice:[Int] = []
var proxycountry:[String] = []

var databaseRef : FIRDatabaseReference!

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return proxyname.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ProxiesTableViewCell
    cell.countryFlag.image = UIImage(named: proxycountry[indexPath.row])
    cell.NameLabel.text = proxyname[indexPath.row]
    cell.priceLabel.text = "$" + String(proxyprice[indexPath.row])
    return(cell)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    //add code
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ProxiesTableView.delegate = self
    ProxiesTableView.dataSource = self

    getData()
}

func getData() {
    databaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference()

    /*
     proxyname = ["50 Proxies (24 Hours)", "100 Proxies", "10 Proxies", "60 Proxies (48 Hours)"]
     proxyprice = [600, 140, 60, 10]
     proxycountry = ["CA", "UK", "UK", "US"]
     */

    self.databaseRef.child("ProxiesItemsFeed").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let proxynames = snapshot.key as String! {
            self.proxyname.append(proxynames)   
                self.databaseRef.child("ProxiesItemsFeed").child(proxynames).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

                    if let country = snapshot.key as String! {
                        self.proxycountry.append(country)
                    }

                    if let price = snapshot.value as! Int! {
                        self.proxyprice.append(price)
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you add *print(snapshot)* as the first line inside the closure. Is it printing anything? Second question: how many nodes are you iterating over with .childAdded? Last thing is you are missing a tableView.reloadData() inside the closure - however, if you have 1000 child nodes that would reload your tableView 1000 times and wouldn't be very efficient. There are a few options to help with that but we need more info first before suggesting a solution.

Comment: I got it to work now, but every time I reload the page there is an index out of range error.

Comment: Do you mean reload the *tableView*? And on what line is the error occurring?

Comment: @Jay When i reload the ViewController, I get an index out of bounds error at line 26

Comment: Please look at your question. How would we know what line 26 is?

Comment: @Jay Line 26 in the code, cell.countryFlag.image = UIImage...

Comment: Here's the issue. You are using three different arrays and (at least) one of them is getting out of sync with the others; meaning that the proxyname array does not have the same number of elements as the proxycounty array. You will need to investigate how those arrays are being populated to get the answer. You may also want to consider creating a an array that holds proxy objects, where each object has three vars:  .name, .county, and .price.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a `tableView.reloadData()` inside your *completion handler* (i.e., the one in your `getData()` method).

Method documentation:

> Call this method to reload all the data that is used to construct the table, including cells, section headers and footers, index arrays, and so on.

Comment: @user7780338 Your `if let price = ...` looks weird. Shouldn't that be `if let price = snapshot.value as? Int`? Are you sure you aren't getting any runtime errors?

Comment: I'm not getting any runtime errors, everything works fine except the cell can't be populated because the array is nil at the end of the getData() function.

Comment: @user7780338 Please try using `as? String` and `as? Int` as the test condition in your `getData()`. Might help…

Comment: Doesnt do anything.

Comment: @user7780338 Please update the code in your question with the above suggestions.